# Insert into table from select orderBy , limit without additional ordering

Tags: mysql

I need to pull 16M rows from table , and data need to by ordered by `ModifiedUtc` column

this 16M rows returns some join this is not pure data from table.

So i would like to create table and insert there allready joined data and sorted like this

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable AS (some compliated select order by ModifiedUtc)
```

question, if i now query this new table by some portions using `limit 15000 then limit 15000 30000` and so on, can i skip ordering by `ModifiedUtc` ?

Answer (score 2):

Every query reads the table in some index order, depending on which index is used to read the table. If no other index, then it will use the clustered index, i.e. the primary key.

If you use LIMIT, you should precede it with ORDER BY to be clear and ensure you get the subset of rows you intend.

If the query uses an index that matches the ORDER BY, then the sorting will be a no-op.